# Get ram manufacturer

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Does anyone know a way to programmatically retrieve the ram memory manufacturer?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be difficult in C or C++. You'll have to use WMI that implies COM. A simple workaround would be vbs: http://activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/computermanagement/hardware/

Comment: It is worth nothing that not every manufacturer writes its name to the EEPROM on board their RAM modules, so even if you find a way to access this data, it may not have everything that you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WINAPI, you should be able to call GetSystemFirmwareTable to retrieve the SMBIOS table, and then parse the table to extract that information.

See this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724379%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

And this

http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.0.pdf

The other option, as mentioned by ruslik, is to use WMI, as described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

(you're looking for objects of type Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray)

I'm not sure which way would be easier. Both seem hard.

Answer (score 6):

Modern RAM chips have an additional EPROM on board that contains a lot of information about the RAM. The standard for this is SPD, or Serial Presence Detect. At least some versions of SPD include a JDEC manufacturer's code.

Look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) for some introductory information on SPD. Not every RAM chip has the information you need, and not every BIOS exposes it, but the article should get you started on handling this stuff in those cases where it's possible.

Comment: Don't you need ring0 for that?

Comment: I didn't get that specific! If the OP is running on an embedded system or MS-DOS then he doesn't. Otherwise, sure, you either need to install a driver that will let you use Ring 0 functionality from user space, or hope that the operating system already provides something equivalent. Heh, on Windows you might be able to simply remote-control HWINFO or similar program. My answer is a starting step pointer, not a complete cookbook.

Comment: @ruslik, no, but you probably need administrator rights - look at CPU-Z for instance.

Comment: @iconiK sorry for dissapointing you, but if you take a look at the end of the cpuz executable, you'll find several drivers. They are saved as temporary files and loaded, so it uses ring0.