# How do I get the RAM manufacturer on MacOS using Python 3?

Tags: python, macos, hardware, ram, system-information

I'm working on a benchmarking application, and I thought it would be useful if users could see the manufacturer of their RAM. I came across this post: [Get ram manufacturer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172384/get-ram-manufacturer), which was very helpful for finding the manufacturer on Windows. However, it didn't answer the question of how I would get the manufacturer of RAM on MacOS.

I came across many libraries for finding system information, such as `psutil` and `system-info`. However, none of the libraries I found could find the manufacturer of RAM on MacOS.

I also tried running `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` from Python, but that only returns information for the amount of memory installed, not the manufacturer of the memory.

However, I do see that in the "System Information" application on MacOS, you can view the manufacturer of your RAM, as shown in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGgwv.png. But that still doesn't solve the problem of how I would get the manufacturer from that application into Python.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will be displayed if the RAM being used is from more than one manufacturer. Most of the time all the RAM cards will come from the same maker. But systems with custom modifications may have a mix. Like having a car with 3 tires from 1 maker and the 4th tire from another maker.

Comment: I'm not sure, as on my computer both of the DIMMs are manufactured by SK Hynix.

Comment: A good system-info application should show you the details on each DIMM separately, including vendor and model ID and maybe other things from their SPD ROMs, and currently in-use timings.  For just one line on a benchmark program, you might not want to write a UI for all that, and just display the current memory clock frequency and the vendor name if all the same, or "mixed" otherwise.  Hopefully also something like "dual channel DDR4-2666" or "2x DDR4-2666" to indicate a count of DIMMs and/or memory channels.  (Both DIMMs on one channel have capacity but not bandwidth...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system_profiler SPMemoryDataType` should have the info you need.

Here's the output on my machine, that matches the screenshot you provided, but that you can easily parse.

```
Memory:

    Memory Slots:

      ECC: Disabled
      Upgradeable Memory: No

        BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0:

          Size: 16 GB
          Type: DDR4
          Speed: 2400 MHz
          Status: OK
          Manufacturer: Micron
          Part Number: 16ATS2G64HZ-2G6B1
          Serial Number: -

        BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0:

          Size: 16 GB
          Type: DDR4
          Speed: 2400 MHz
          Status: OK
          Manufacturer: Micron
          Part Number: 16ATS2G64HZ-2G6B1
          Serial Number: -
```